# One line QMessageDialog

Tags: qt, qtquick2

Coming from C# background and now trying to develop apps using Qt Quick (due to cross platform compatibility), is it possible to create QMessageDialog using only one line? In C#, we can create MessageBox using only one line such as this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello","Title");
```

However in Qt Quick, from my knowledge we need to create MessageDialog object first,

```
MessageDialog {
    id: messageDialog
    title: "May I have your attention please"
    text: "It's so cool that you are using Qt Quick."
    Component.onCompleted: visible = false
}
```

and then use the object;

```
MainForm {
    btnOpenDB.onClicked: {
        messageDialog.text = "Another Hello"
        messageDialog.title = "Another Title"
        messageDialog.visible = true;
    }
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

As you can see, I need to use more than one line to just create MessageDialog. Is it possible to create one line MessageDialog in QtQuick?

Comment: I don't see a one line solution to this in Qt.

Comment: You can wrap it in your own .JS function, which takes those two arguments, creates the dialog and shows it. That might make a reasonable answer to this question, too.

Comment: @Georg Dang it. Even in QWidgets one line MessageBox can be done by creating static function with overload.

Comment: @hyde Im still new in Qt Quick so Im not sure how that can be done. A simple example will helps a lot.